# If ready do else add to queue

Tags: java, android, queue

I'm using a complex closed api. I want to create a super simple way to use it.
Basicaly, it has the following behaviour:

```
boolean everythingReady = false;

API.start(new Callback() {
    public void onReady()
    {
        API.invite(new Callback2() {
            public void onReady()
            {
                everythingReady = true;
            }
        });
    }
});

while (!everythingReady); // Wait

API.send("hello);
API.send("What's up");
```

This is a chat API and the above code is "pseudo" java.

What I want to do now is:

```
API.start();
API.invite();
API.send("Hello);
API.send("What's up");
```

these methods would wait until each above has been correctly loaded (onReady called) to run. (eg: `if (!apiStarted) addToQueue else do invite`)

Is there a way to do that in java (as I can't edit at all the API sources).
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
API.start(new Callback() {
    public void onReady()
    {
        API.invite(new Callback() {
            public void onReady()
            {
                API.send("hello");
                API.send("What's up");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This way the send methods will be called only after `invite` is ready.

Comment: This is nearly what I've already done but I don't want to use a cllback system. Is there a way to add a method to a queue and retry to run it if the starting condition isn't set yet?

Comment: What is wrong with callbacks? You do all that inside a single function and call it. Looks like the API methods also needs callbacks, so you must use them at least for that.